# rails subtract two strings in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, ruby-on-rails-3, subtraction

I want to subtract two strings

lets say "hello world" - "world" = hello

I found a tutorial which does the same

http://shmuel.ahdut.com/2007/09/1-require-digestsha1-2-class-user.html

The problem i find here is it i use the function in rails console its working well.

but in views it is showing problems

undefined method `-' for " asd S Turbo":String

i have added the function in the controller

```
def -(s)
 self.gsub(s, "")
end
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this in a view, add it as a helper function. That method doesn't belong in the controller.

```
module YourControllerHelper

  def clean(original, target)
    original.gsub(target, '')
  end

end
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= clean('hello world', 'world') =>
```

That would leave a space after "hello", so you might want to call `rstrip` on it or something.

Answer (score 0):

If that method works for you, you can add it to the string class in an initializer

config/initializers/string_extensions.rb

```
class String

  def -(s)
    gsub(s, "")
  end

end
```